# HTML adding website prefix to external url's

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, url, audio

I have an array of URLs that I am using to dynamically change what music is being played in a browser audio source.

```
const songs = [{
    song: 'Song Name',
    src: '‪https://external-url.com/SongName.mp3'
}, {
    song: 'Song Name',
    src: '‪https://external-url.com/SongName.mp3'
}, {
    song: 'Song Name',
    src: '‪https://external-url.com/SongName.mp3'
}];
```

Then I randomly generate an index and update the source of the audio in HTML to play that file. There's no issue there. However, SOME of the songs refuse to play and when inspecting the console, it's setting the URL as

```
GET file:///B:/Coding/MusicBox/%E2%80%AA‪https://external-url.com/SongName.mp3 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It doesn't happen to every song. Some play perfectly and use the correct external URL as the source but others always have the base URL appended to the front. I do NOT have a base URL set in the header of the site and the format for the URL's are all exactly the same.

Has anyone seen an issue like this before?

---

Edits:

The Random Number Function:

```
function randomSong() {
    let title = document.getElementById('currentSong');
    let player = document.getElementById('songSource');
    let pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
    title.innerHTML = songs[pick].song;
    player.src = songs[pick].src;
}
```

The github repo
https://github.com/Hardytack/music-player

Comment: can you share the code to generate random index?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow, When you ask a question please share your code also so that we can answer specifically instead of guessing.

Comment: Hello! I added the random number function as well as a link to the github repo. I hope that helps!